# MongooseServerSelectionError: read ECONNRESET

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, backend, mongodb-atlas

I'm trying to connect my Nodejs application to MongoDB Atlas but it's throwing an error.

**Here is the error message:**

> This is the error in the catch block: MongooseServerSelectionError:
>   read ECONNRESET DB connection error: read ECONNRESET

**Below is the code for my Nodejs application:**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config();

//db connection
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  })
  .then(() => console.log("DB Connected"))
  .catch(err => {
    console.log("This is the error in the catch block: " + err);
  });

mongoose.connection.on("error", err => {
  console.log(`DB connection error: ${err.message}`);
});
```

**NOTE:-** I declared .env file in which I have a variable MONGO_URI to hold the secret key required for connecting to MongoDB Atlas.

Comment: Did you whitelist your IP address on Atlas?

Comment: Atlas requires SSL by default, does your connection string call for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was connected to a Wi-Fi connection that was having some policies due to which it was placing some restrictions and thus I was getting the above error.

I connected to another Wi-Fi connection ( not having any policies or restrictions ) and that fixed my problem.

Cheers!

Comment: Had a similar situation. I just had to disable the VPN. Thank you